# Code Improvement Needed

Tags: vba, excel, export

This is as far as I got with it however it is now only copying the active.sheet multiple times rather than cycling through.

The idea of what I was trying to achieve was for a macro to run and covert every worksheet as a .csv. The filename of that .csv would be the worksheet name which is decided by another macro than runs earlier in the flow.

Any ideas on how to circle through, as I said before. I am fairly new to code hence why I am asking.

Sub Export_Sub_Xpath()
    '
    ' Export_Sub_Xpath Macro
    '

```
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    For i = 1 To WS_Count



    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
    PathName = "" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ws.Name & ".csv"
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Range("B3000").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    PathName = "" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ws.Name & ".csv"
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs PathName = "" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ws.Name & ".csv"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=PathName, _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Describe your task, please. What code should doing?

Comment: How can the code do exactly what you need and yet not work?  Do you **really** need code that doesn't work?

Comment: Try adding `Option Explicit` at the top of your code and `Dim Pathname As String` in this sub. I can run this code with no problems!

Comment: yep, add Dim PathName as String

Comment: Runs fine for me BUT you do need to change one line from `WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count` to `WS_Count = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count`, and also the `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs...` should be `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs...`. Alternatively, change the rest of the code so that it references the active workbook.

Comment: Move `Dim ws as worksheet` outside of your loop

Comment: and furthermore, there are charactes which are allowed in sheet names but not in file names, check for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to activate each sheet before copying and saving.  Try this:

```
Sub Export_Sub_Xpath() ' ' Export_Sub_Xpath Macro '
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    WS_Count = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    For i = 1 To WS_Count
            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
            PathName = "" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ws.Name & ".csv"
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Activate  ' You forgeot to Activate Each Sheet before saving
            Columns("A:B").Select
            Range("B3000").Activate                 
            Selection.Copy
            Workbooks.Add
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=PathName, _
                FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
            ActiveWorkbook.Close

Next i

End Sub
```